# DBCP Datasource with Oracle XA Datasource driver in spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

My current web app uses Struts2, Spring, Oracle, Hibernate/JPA and Websphere.
I am writing JUnit tests for my action classes which uses spring-struts plugin.

Since these tests run outside of the WebSphere, I need to configure Datasources in context.xml. Currently, it uses JNDI within WebSphere.

For testing, I am creating a different context file which uses dbcp.BasicDataSource. However, I would like to use it with same driver configured in the WebSphere, which is `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`.

Does this combination work or I need to make any changes? Here is what my current context looks like for this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mylocalhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = myoraservice) ) )"/>
    <property name="username" value="usera"/>
    <property name="password" value="passb"/>
</bean>
```

I certainly don't need 2 phase commit feature. Since it only deals with one database. However, I do need connection pooling and high performance, since the database is huge and lot of database calls required.

If not above, what is the alternative? Simple `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` works okay?

Comment: Have you tried it? Also I wouldn't recommend commons-dbcp but something like [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) or [tomcat JDBC](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html).

Comment: @M.Deinum `I wouldn't recommend commons-dbcp` Can you explain why?

Comment: Judging by your package structure you are using commons-dbca, which is old and has it threading and contention issues and it isn't JDBC4 compliant (although commons-dbcp2 is).

Comment: @M.Deinum. Thanks. I cannot use the newer one because of the Java Version.